# Problem with NDSolve and If

Tags: differential-equations

If `T=T1`, program can calculate. But, when `T = T1*If[Abs[q2[t] - q2d] < e1 && Abs[q2'[t]] < e1, 0, 1]`, program can not calculate.  Why?

```
c1 = 0.725; c2 = 0.3179; c3 = 0.3147; F1 = 0.26; F2 = 0.116; b1 = 
0.6236; b2 = 0.1223;  c = 0.01; q2d = Pi/6; e1 = 0.001;
m11 = c1 + c3 + 2*c3*Cos[q2[t]];
m12 = c2 + c3*Cos[q2[t]];
m22 = c2;
H1 = -c3 (2 q1'[t] + q2'[t]) q2'[t] Sin[q2[t]];
H2 = c3*Sin[q2[t]]*(q1'[t])^2;

SGN2 = Sign[q2'[t]];
SGN1 = Which[q1'[t] > 0, 1, q1'[t] < 0, -1, q1'[t] = 0, T/F1];

S1 = q2[t] - q2d + 3/5*Abs[q2'[t]]^(5/3)*Sign[q2'[t]];
v2 = -Sign[q2'[t]]*(Abs[q2'[t]])^(1/3) - Sign[S1]*(Abs[S1])^(1/3);


T1 = (m12 - m11 (1/m12) m22) v2 + (H1 + SGN1*F1 + b1*q1'[t]) - 
   m11 (1/m12) (H2 + SGN2*F2 + b2*q2'[t]);
T = T1*If[Abs[q2[t] - q2d] < e1 && Abs[q2'[t]] < e1, 0, 1];


eq1 = m11*q1''[t] + m12*q2''[t] + H1 == T - SGN1*F1 - b1*q1'[t];
eq2 = m12*q1''[t] + m22*q2''[t] + H2 == -b2*q2'[t] - SGN2*F2;
eq3 = {q1[0] == Pi/5, q2[0] == Pi/4, q1'[0] == 0, q2'[0] == 0};

t1 = 10;
s = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {q1, q2, q1', q2'}, {t, 0, t1} ];
Plot[{Evaluate[q1[t] /. s], Evaluate[q2[t] /. s]}, {t, 0, t1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large];
Plot[{Evaluate[q1'[t] /. s], Evaluate[q2'[t] /. s]}, {t, 0, t1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: In your Which you have q1'[t]=0 and that should be q1'[t]==0.

In your definition and use of T the value of t appears to be unknown at that point when you need it and thus Mathematica If cannot determine whether the result should be 0 or 1. To demonstrate this you need to either do some tracing on T or perhaps use T:= along with using Print in perhaps a tricky way to be able to show the value of T but without changing the value.

Comment: The issue relating to the use of `T` in `Which` identified by @Bill can be circumvented by setting `q1'[0] == e1` as an initial condition in `NDSolve`.  However, the differential equation then becomes stiff at about 4.95, when the `If` is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question,@bill.Moreover,Please send me a right code so that I can learn more.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question,@bbgodfrey.Moreover,Please send me a right code so that I can learn more.

Comment: I suggest you not use variables recursively.  As it stands, `SGN1` depends on `T`, and `T` depends on `SGN1`.  I recommend that you eliminate `T` from `SGN1` or change the boundary condition as I suggested in my last comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help,but I am a beginner.I am so sorry,I can not undestand what your mean.Would you like to show the modifications code directly?@bbgodfrey

Comment: @Michael E2，Please help me

Comment: @belisarius，Please help me

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard，Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions q2 and q2' should not be here in the conditions of "If".
In other words, the differential equations in "NDSolve" should be determined.

---

It is my fault

The function "If" can be understand by "NDSolve".

The core issue is that the definition of variable "SGN1" is wrong.

The value of "SGN1" when t=0 can not be calculated, because it is a cycle definition.

Comment: I am sorry，I think your answer is so abstract.Mover , I would be a pleasure,if you can offer some example.